# Check the checbox corresponding to node key in Dynatree

Tags: jquery, dynatree, jquery-dynatree

I am storing some data according to the checked nodes.For each checked node i will be storing the key in database. Now suppose when a come again to the same page say in EDIT mode of my application i need to check the nodes corresponding to the keys stored in database. I have been looking for the same but unable to find it.Please provide any useful link or part of documentation where i can find the same.

Comment: you really need to improve your question... add some codes or the things that you have done..

Comment: thanks for replying but i got it with 

**tree.selectKey(Key).select(false); to uncheck the checkbox**

**tree.selectKey(Key).select(true);to check the checkbox** dynamically.
**
All we need is the key of the node.

Comment: looks like you need to use `jQuery.ajax()` to get the nodes value from the database.. and check it like you mentioned it above